# MFMessageComposeViewController shows blank white screen on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to present MFMessageComposeViewController to my view controller having body text and video attachment. It is working fine on iPhone 5 with version 10.3.3 and also on 6s plus with version 11.0.3 but it is showing white blank screen(no body text , no attachment) in iPhone 6s and iPhone 5s with version number 10.3.2. I am posting my code below. Please correct me  if my code is not correct.

func shareVideoWithMessage(videoPath : URL, message : String, viewController : UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

```
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self

        if dictionary.value(forKey: "isCampaign") as! Bool{
            controller.body = "Campaign by \(dictionary.value(forKey: "username") as! String) on MyApp. Download the my app: www.google.com"
        }
        else{
            controller.body = "Submission by \(dictionary.value(forKey: "username") as! String) on myApp. Download the My app: www.google.com"
        }

        var videoData = Data()

        do{
            videoData =  try NSData(contentsOfFile: (videoPath.relativePath), options: NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped) as Data
        }
        catch{
            completion(false)
        }

        controller.addAttachmentData(videoData as Data, typeIdentifier: "video/.mp4", filename: "video.mp4")
        viewController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
            completion(true)
        })


    }
    else{
        completion(false)

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue.. Have you found any solution